# Consuming a stream in the context of a Servicestack client

Tags: .net-4.0, servicestack, httpwebresponse

While I have already learned how I can [easily write to the response stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040680/servicestack-and-returning-a-stream), I was wondering whether in the context of a ServiceStack client (e.g. `ServiceClientBase`) I can gain access to the server's response stream.

Before I start accessing the `HttpWebResponse` object I wanted to double-check that I do not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this earlier answer for examples of how to access the [underlying raw response types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580459/85785).

Also the [C# ServiceClient wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client) is the authoritative documentation on ServiceStack's built in C#/.NET service clients. It includes a section on different ways of [accessing the underlying raw response](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#support-for-native-built-in-response-types), including via the Response stream:

```
using (Stream responseStream = client.Get<Stream>("/poco/World")) {
    var dto = responseStream.ReadFully().FromUtf8Bytes().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
    dto.Result //Hello, World
}
```