# Consuming a ServiceStack service to get Raw Bytes

Tags: json, rest, servicestack

I'm consuming a rest service with ServiceSatck framework. Now I want to get the raw bytes.
Suppose the url is http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/Myservice/api/hello.

In this [Seeing the Http Response content in ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580262/seeing-the-http-response-content-in-servicestack) it seems to be using get method but I used post method.

**EDIT:**

I used the code

```
`var x = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx/Myservice/api/hello".PostJsonToUrl(new MyRequestDTO() { RequestData = hello }).ToArray();
```

I did get the raw bytes. However comparing with [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) method, there are about 200 bytes lost.

Using RestSharp method, the code is:

```
        var aResponse = restClient.Execute(MyRequestDTO);
        byte[] bytes = aResponse.RawBytes;
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [ServiceStack's typed .NET  clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client) shows how you can access the raw bytes:

```
byte[] responseBytes = client.Get<byte[]>("/poco/World");
var dto = responseBytes.FromUtf8Bytes().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
dto.Result //Hello, World
```

Or as a Stream:

```
using (Stream responseStream = client.Get<Stream>("/poco/World")) {
  var dto = responseStream.ReadFully().FromUtf8Bytes().FromJson<PocoResponse>();
  dto.Result //Hello, World
}
```

You don't even need to use the type clients for getting raw bytes, you can just as easily use a [HTTP Util extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils):

```
byte[] rawBytes = "http://example.org/Myservice/api/hello".GetBytesFromUrl();
```

#### HOW to POST JSON and retrieve bytes using HTTP Utils extensions

```
var dtoBytes = new MyRequestDTO { ... }.ToJson().ToUtf8Bytes();
var responseBytes = "http://example.org/Myservice/api/hello".PostBytesToUrl(
  dtoBytes, contentType:"application/json");
```

Comment: I want to use the third one since the first one is not working. What is argument for GetBytesFromUrl? Suppose I have a request. Is it "http://example.org/Myservice/api/hello".GetBytesFromUrl("*/*", new MyRequest() {RequestData = MyDTO})?

Comment: No, there's no Request DTO. HTTP Utils is for calling any 3rd Party HTTP Urls it doesn't use Request DTOs. Just specify what you want on the Url and read the docs for more info.

Comment: I want to post a request(a dto object) to the api and get the raw bytes from the response, but the first one's argument(client.Get<byte[]) must be a string rather than a dto object.

Comment: @Love Don't use comments to ask new questions, be specific on what answer you're seeking and include it in the original question. Also read the docs, it feels like you haven't bothered.

Comment: Please see my updated code, I do have a request dto to be posted to the server.

Comment: @Love Why would you think `PostJsonToUrl` returns bytes when it returns a string? The most obvious API to use is `PostBytesToUrl` to POST a HTTP Request which returns bytes. But honestly if you have it working with RestSharp just use that, it doesn't seem that you're understanding what the HTTP Utils extension methods do.

Comment: Because if you use PostBytesToUrl, you have to convert the argument from dto object to byte[]. I am not sure how to do it. Of course, using RestSharp is fine. I just want to learn something about ServiceStack.

Comment: HTTP Utils is for any HTTP Service it doesn't have any opinion tying it to only ServiceStack services. I've updated the answer to show how to use `PostBytesToUrl`.

Comment: I will give up this method and stick on RestSharp. It(PostBytesToUrl) returned 0 bytes. But many thanks for your input.